# JS library to transform JSON duplicate data into array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I know what I want to achieve, but don't know how to express this in short terms and how to find what I want, so I'll try to describe and maybe somebody will point me to the right path.

I want to transfrom results to contain only one unique, nested into arrays of object according to names of object properties. As an example, I would like to transform this:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Mister", "surname": "X", "order.id": 1, "orders.item_id": 3, "orders.delivered": true },  
  { "id": 1, "name": "Mister", "surname": "X", "order.id": 2, "orders.item_id": 5, "orders.delivered": true },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Missis", "surname": "X", "order.id": 3, "orders.item_id": 7, "orders.delivered": true },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Missis", "surname": "X", "order.id": 4, "orders.item_id": 6, "orders.delivered": true }
]
```

into

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Mister", "surname": "X", "orders": [
    { "id": 1, "item_id": 3, "delivered": true },
    { "id": 2, "item_id": 5, "delivered": true }
  ]},
  { "id": 2, "name": "Missis", "surname": "X", "orders": [
    { "id": 3, "item_id": 7, "delivered": true },
    { "id": 4, "item_id": 6, "delivered": true }
  ] } 
]
```

Data itself isn't excatly what needs to be transformed, there might be other fields and that's data why can be nested is has prefix name `orders` separated from joined column name with dot. There's no limit how much nesting can object properties have, e.g. could be even `orders.items.tags.name`. I need to get this done in `Javascript`. I don't want an ORM. I want to perform these actions with JSON data I already got.

Maybe such action/data tranformation has a name for it and I can look up libraries myself? Is there Javascript library that can perform this with just data you supply to it?

Comment: This will be entirely down to how you have structured your database. It is very unlikely that anybody has exactly the same. You will have to write this yourself. Also asking for library recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow, you may ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's unlikely that JS would understand key names with periods in them:`orders.id` for example. They would have to be renamed to `ordersId`.

Comment: JS objects can use `orders.id` as a key for object property, it just would need to be accessed with as `object["orders.id"]`.

Comment: I don't think that works with object destructuring which is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method of getting an output like you want using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It produces an object with keys that represent the main `id` (as that will be easier to use that an array of objects), and assumes that the order keys are renamed to something usable by the destructuring:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", orders_id: 1, item_id: 3, delivered: true },  
  { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", orders_id: 2, item_id: 5, delivered: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", orders_id: 3, item_id: 7, delivered: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", orders_id: 4, item_id: 6, delivered: true }
];

function transform(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((obj, c) => {

    // destructure the current object
    const { id, name, surname, ...order } = c;

    // if the id doesn't already exist create a new one with an empty orders array
    obj[id] = obj[id] || { name, surname, orders: [ ] };

    // push the order into the array
    obj[id].orders.push(order);

    // return the object for the next iteration
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

const out = transform(data);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using the function `reduce` to group the objects and the function `Object.values` to extract the desired array.

```js
let arr = [  { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", 'orders.id': 1, 'orders.item_id': 3, 'orders.delivered': true },    { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", 'orders.id': 2, 'orders.item_id': 5, 'orders.delivered': true },  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", 'orders.id': 3, 'orders.item_id': 7, 'orders.delivered': true },  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", 'orders.id': 4, 'orders.item_id': 6, 'orders.delivered': true }],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {id, name, surname, ...orders}) => {
       let item_id = orders['orders.item_id'], delivered = orders['orders.delivered'];
       (a[name] || (a[name] = {id, name, surname, orders: []})).orders.push({id: orders['orders.id'], item_id, delivered});   
       return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array#reduce() to create a groupBy object map and then get the array values of that object as your resultant

Note you can't use a dot in property names

```js
const grouped = data.reduce((map,{id,name,surname,...rest})=>{
  !map.has(id) && map.set(id, {id, name, surname, orders:[]})  
  map.get(id).orders.push({...rest})
  return map
},new Map);

const res = [...grouped.values()]

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", order_id: 1, item_id: 3, delivered: true },  
  { id: 1, name: "Mister", surname: "X", order_id: 2, item_id: 5, delivered: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", order_id: 3, item_id: 7, delivered: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Missis", surname: "X", order_id: 4, item_id: 6, delivered: true }
]

</script>
```